# How to a create a new dataframe of consolidated values from multiple columns in R

Tags: r, for-loop, sum, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe, df1, that looks like the following:

| sample | 99_Ape_1 | 93_Cat_1 | 87_Ape_2 | 84_Cat_2 | 90_Dog_1 | 92_Dog_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 3 | 1 | 7 | 4 | 6 |
| B | 5 | 9 | 7 | 0 | 3 | 7 |
| C | 6 | 8 | 9 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| D | 3 | 9 | 0 | 5 | 8 | 3 |

I want to consolidate the dataframe by summing the values based on animal present in the header row, i.e. by "Ape", "Cat", "Dog", and end up with the following dataframe:

| sample | Ape | Cat | Dog |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 10 | 10 |
| B | 12 | 9 | 10 |
| C | 15 | 10 | 3 |
| D | 3 | 14 | 11 |

I have created a list that represents all the animals called "animals_list"

I have then created a list of dataframes that subsets each animal into a separate dataframe with:

```
animals_extract <- c()

for (i in 1:length(animals_list)){
  species_extract[[i]] <- df1[, grep(animals_list[i], names(df1))]
}
```

I am then trying to sum each variable in the row by sample:

```
for (i in 1:length(species_extract)){
  species_extract[[i]]$total <- rowSums(species_extract[[i]])
}
```

and then create a dataframe 'animal_total' by binding all values in the new 'total' column.

```
animal_total <- NULL

for (i in 1:length(species_extract)){
  animal_total[i] <- cbind(species_extract[[i]]$total)
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work at all and I think I may have taken the wrong route. Any help would be really appreciated!

EDIT: my dataframe has over 300 animals, meaning incorporating use of my list of identifiers (animals_list) would be highly appreciated! I would also note that some column names do not follow the structure, "number_animal_number" and therefore I can't use a repetitive search (sorry!).

Answer (score 4):

a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
library(rlist)
#set data to data.table format
setDT(df1)
# split column 2:n by regex on column names
L <- split.default(df1[,-1], gsub(".*_(.*)_.*", "\\1", names(df1)[-1]))
# Bind together again
data.table(sample = df1$sample, 
           as.data.table(list.cbind(lapply(L, rowSums))))
#    sample Ape Cat Dog
# 1:      A   3  10  10
# 2:      B  12   9  10
# 3:      C  15  10   3
# 4:      D   3  14  11
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for, though unfortunately not all the column names have the same structure of "number_animal_number". Is there a way to use the list of names I have created to do the same thing? Sorry for not being clear in my question.

Comment: Perfect. Somehow I have to learn data.table coding!

Comment: @code_rookie is is possible to catch the wanted column in a regex (probable answer is Yes ;-) ), if so, you can use the method above. If you are not sure how, you can ask *a new question* asking for a regex, with your colnames as sample data.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** After clarification:
This may work depending on the other names of your animals. but this is a start:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -sample
  ) %>% 
  mutate(name1 = str_extract(name, '(?<=\\_)(.*?)(?=\\_)')) %>% 
  group_by(sample, name1) %>% 
  summarise(sum=sum(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = name1,
    values_from= sum
  )
```

Output:

```
  sample   Ape   Cat   Dog
  <chr>  <int> <int> <int>
1 A          3    10    10
2 B         12     9    10
3 C         15    10     3
4 D          3    14    11
```

**First answer:**
Here is how we could do it with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Cat = rowSums(select(., contains("Cat"))),
         Ape = rowSums(select(., contains("Ape"))),
         Dog = rowSums(select(., contains("Dog")))) %>% 
  select(sample, Cat, Ape, Dog)
```

```
  sample   Ape   Cat   Dog
  <chr>  <int> <int> <int>
1 A          3    10    10
2 B         12     9    10
3 C         15    10     3
4 D          3    14    11
```

Comment: Thank you! My entire dataframe has about 300 animals, meaning the code this way will be very long.. Is there a way to use the list of names I have created to do the same thing? Sorry for not being clear in my question. I will edit my question to make this apparent.

Comment: Oh I see. I will have a look.

Comment: Please see my update. This might work depending on the pattern of your other column names. Tell me!

Comment: This would be my approach as well.

Comment: Thank you both. This method worked a treat after I cleaned up the column names to give it a regular pattern as demonstrated in the example dataframe. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative data.table solution

```
library(data.table)

# Construct data table 
dt <- as.data.table(list(sample = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                         `99_Ape_1` = c(2, 5, 6, 3), 
                         `93_Cat_1` = c(3, 9, 8, 9), 
                         `87_Ape_2` = c(1, 7, 9, 0),
                         `84_Cat_2` = c(7, 0, 2, 5),
                         `90_Dog_1` = c(4, 3, 3, 8),
                         `92_Dog_2` = c(6, 7, 0, 3)))

# Alternatively convert existing dataframe
# dt <- setDT(df)

# Use Regex pattern to drop ids from column names
names(dt) <- gsub("((^[0-9_]{3})|(_[0-9]{1}$))", "", names(dt))

# Pivot long (columns to rows)
dt <- melt(dt, id.vars = "sample")

# Aggregate sample by variable
dt <- dt[, .(value=sum(value)), by=.(sample, variable)]

# Unpivot (rows to colums)
dcast(dt, sample ~ variable)

#     sample Ape Cat Dog
# 1:      A   3  10  10
# 2:      B  12   9  10
# 3:      C  15  10   3
# 4:      D   3  14  11
```

Alternatively, leaving the column names as is (after comment from OP to previous answer) and assuming that there are multiple observations of the same samples:

```
dt <- as.data.table(list(sample = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A"), 
                         `99_Ape_1` = c(2, 5, 6, 3, 1), 
                         `93_Cat_1` = c(3, 9, 8, 9, 1), 
                         `87_Ape_2` = c(1, 7, 9, 0, 1),
                         `84_Cat_2` = c(7, 0, 2, 5, 1),
                         `90_Dog_1` = c(4, 3, 3, 8, 1),
                         `92_Dog_2` = c(6, 7, 0, 3, 1)))

dt

#     sample 99_Ape_1 93_Cat_1 87_Ape_2 84_Cat_2 90_Dog_1 92_Dog_2
# 1:      A        2        3        1        7        4        6
# 2:      B        5        9        7        0        3        7
# 3:      C        6        8        9        2        3        0
# 4:      D        3        9        0        5        8        3
# 5:      A        1        1        1        1        1        1

# Pivot long (columns to rows)
dt <- melt(dt, id.vars = "sample")

# Aggregate sample by variable
dt <- dt[, .(value=sum(value)), by=.(sample, variable)]

# Unpivot (rows to colums)
dcast(dt, sample ~ variable)

#     sample 99_Ape_1 93_Cat_1 87_Ape_2 84_Cat_2 90_Dog_1 92_Dog_2
# 1:      A        3        4        2        8        5        7
# 2:      B        5        9        7        0        3        7
# 3:      C        6        8        9        2        3        0
# 4:      D        3        9        0        5        8        3
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My edit is not to say I wish to keep the same column names, I wish to aggregate them into consolidated columns based on animals but as I have many variables and they do not follow a repetitive pattern, I hoped to use the list 'animals_list' to search and consolidate by. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: If the animals list is just a character vector of values matching the column names then the answer is valid. If it is a dataframe mapping the values in the column names to the species of the animal in question then this requires an additional join after the pivot long transformation to allow the data to be aggregated by the target values instead of the column names. 

If the animals list is a key part of the required solution you should include an minimimum working example it in the question.